# HTMLUnit Execute only one Function

Tags: java, javascript, htmlunit

I am using HTMLUnit to crawl webpages. The problem is that setting Javascript on really slow down the process, i need to execute only one function, is it possible to skip all JS except the one function i set in the executeJavaScript()?

Comment: I dnt think soo such facility exist in HtmlUnit

Answer (score 0):

maybe

```
             webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
```

at start and once you are at the point you want to use it again

```
             webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

I didn't test it though!